# Check condition for multiple criteria?

Tags: vb.net

How would the logic for something like this work.? Say I have 4 Combobox, and 2 listboxes. The first combobox is required for any operation to carry on. Easy enough to check for that by doing something like `If Not ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1 Then`

Then, ComboBox 2-4 are optional but has to be taken into account. It would be a mess to do multiple nested If checks, so is there a simpler, easier solution? I'll attach a screenshot to show what I mean

[image: Example]

I don't want to do something like:

```
If Not RequiredFruit.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    If Not Combo1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        If Not Combo2.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
```

There's gotta be a better method?

Comment: *"ComboBox 2-4 are optional but has to be taken into account"*. Taken into account how? That's just far too vague. As general advice, you can combine multiple conditions into a single expression using `AndAlso` and/or `OrElse` in appropriate combinations. Boolean logic is still Boolean logic.

Comment: Meaning, if combobox 2-3 IS selected, those options has to be "recorded" or processed when the button is clicked. If they're not selected, as in, no option has been made, then the program continue on

Comment: I would have many `AndAlso` statement to check for every variation of the options, I am trying to see if there is another smarter way to do it

Comment: I don't see how *How many* and *Basket type* can optional. Anyway, this all depends on the final destination of the decision making process. Or *who needs to know?*. I'ld pass each value selected to a specialized class that can reference the User choices when needed. Then assemble/package/select just what has been chosen directly and use defaul values for what has not.

Comment: You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  You're expecting us to guess too much.  My guess is that you can simply use an `If` operator when assigning to appropriate variables, e.g. `color = If(colorComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1, Nothing, colorComboBox.Text)`.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am not being clear. Just imagine having 10 combobox for options. It would be crazy to do so many `If` and `AndAlso` and `Or` statements to check the conditions of all 10 combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways you could do this. If you don't like having nested `If` `AndAlso` `OrElse` here's one such approach using small `Functions` for each selection option.

```
Private Function SelectionCombo2() As String
    If Not ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Return String.Format(", {0}", ComboBox2.SelectedItem)
    Return String.Empty
End Function

Private Function SelectionCombo3() As String
    If ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Return String.Format(", {0}", ComboBox3.SelectedItem)
    Return String.Empty
End Function

Private Function SelectionCombo4() As String
    If ComboBox4.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Return String.Format(", {0}", ComboBox4.SelectedItem)
    Return String.Empty
End Function

Private Function SelectionList1() As String
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Return String.Format(", {0}", ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    Return String.Empty
End Function
```

The control names need changing to be more appropriate.

Then in your `Button` click just test for the first `ComboBox` and display the result. Each `Function` will take care of what to display. It's also possible to compact these separate `Functions` into one if you like this approach.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You have selected {0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", ComboBox1.SelectedItem, SelectionCombo2, SelectionCombo3, SelectionCombo4, SelectionList1))
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You have selected nothing")
    End If
End Sub
```

---

> To make it more compact see below:

Example of using just one `Function` for the `ComboBoxes`:

```
Private Function Selection(Combo As ComboBox) As String
    If Not Combo.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Return String.Format(", {0}", Combo.SelectedItem)
    Return String.Empty
End Function
```

The `Button` display would need changing slightly:

```
      MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You have selected {0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", ComboBox1.SelectedItem, Selection(ComboBox2), Selection(ComboBox3), Selection(ComboBox4), SelectionList1))
```